# I have a 2000 GMC Sierra 5.3L that won't start/run as of today

Tags: engine, stall, gmc, sierra

My truck has died on me 3 times today. When I put it in park and turn it off the doors don't unlock themselves. Then when I tried to start it up again nothing! No sounds, no lights. Then when I do get it started it wants to stall out. All gauges read fine and no warning lights

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an electrical problem, most likely your alternator.  I think we need more info though: you said "then when I do get it started..." — is this by jump starting it?  If it then "wants to stall out" immediately upon disconnecting the jumper cables, I would say there is something wrong with your alternator.  Check system voltage, belt tension, and inspect electrical connections.  You can get the alternator and battery tested for free at many brand name auto parts stores.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is a bad connection on your battery terminals.  When it is running, your alternator is providing power.  Once you stop the engine your battery is not providing enough current, so high current devices don't work.

Disconnect the battery connectors and clean the battery terminal posts and the connectors with a wire brush/sand paper, than reconnect them. See if that helps.

Comment: I had a '98 and found that the 2 connectors on the plus terminal needed to be aligned ; Loose it and rotate the terminals, you should feel them seat together. It was strange, the cable ends were clean and tight but the truck would stop while running down the highway until I aligned the ends.

Comment: Worth taking it to autozone/whatever and having them check the battery/alternator as well...